# Моносостояние (Класс Борга) Каким образом все свойства одного экземпляра становятся свойствами других?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Объясните, пожалуйста, как это работает?

```
class Borg:
    _shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_state
```

Каким образом все свойства одно экземпляра становятся свойствами других? Здесь ведь каждый раз словарю аттрибутов экземпляра класса при инициализации должен присваиваться пустой словарь, а получается наоборот, не понимаю :(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=16&v=VuQdAdOmZbM&feature=emb_logo/ Все очень кратко и понятно, посмотри.

Comment: Я с этого видео и пришёл:) Не понимаю почему происходит не на оборот...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инициализируется словарь при создании класса, а не экземпляра класса.
При создании экземпляра всем экземплярам присваивается ссылка на один и тот же словарь, с которым и работают в итоге все экземпляры.

Вот эта часть выполняется сразу, когда интерпретатор встречает объявление класса:

```
class Borg:
    _shared_state = {}
```

А эта - при создании каждого экземпляра класса:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__ = self._shared_state
```

Проверим, что ссылка получается на один и тот же объект:

```
class Borg:
    _shared_state = {}
    print(id(_shared_state))

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_state
        print(id(self.__dict__))

a = Borg()
b = Borg()
c = Borg()
```

Вывод:

```
140386153522520
140386153522520
140386153522520
140386153522520
```

Тут есть ещё одна тонкость. Когда выполняется строка:

```
self.__dict__ = self._shared_state
```

То вроде бы должно браться значение переменной `_shared_state` из экземпляра класса (ключевое слово `self`). Но своей такой переменной у экземпляра нет, поэтому берётся "статическая" переменная - из описания самого класса. Если в дальнейшем что-то присвоить переменной `self._shared_state`, то она перестанет указывать на статический объект класса и заживёт собственной жизнью, это нужно знать.

Comment: сделайте милость, распишите, пожалуйста, если вас не затруднит по пунктам: что происходит? Потому, что я реально не понимаю вот эту строчку ``` self.__dict__ = self._shared_state ``` . Разве здесь не написано присваивание пустого словаря словарю атрибутов экземпляра класса? т.е. каждый новый экземпляр должен быть без атрибутов...

Comment: @TobaSko Расписал чуть подробнее, хотя наверняка это делали уже до меня 100500 раз в других вопросах.